# PHP Regex: Several searches

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a text like this structure (actually this is html)

"b1-b2" after "abc" several times (or once, or never)

```
abc
    - hello -
    b1 hello b2
    - hello -
    b1 hello b2
```

And I want to change it to

```
abc
    - hello -
    z1 hello z2
    - hello -
    z1 hello z2
```

I can change the first occurence with this

```
$text = preg_replace('/(abc.+?)b1(.+?)b2/s',"$1z1$2z2",$text);
```

The text becomes

```
abc
    - hello -
    z1 hello z2
    - hello -
    b1 hello b2
```

The question is How to change other occurences of "b"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
(a|(?<!^)\G)(.*?)<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>
```

Replace with `$1$2<h2>$3<h2>`.

See demo

```
$re = "/(a|(?<!^)\\G)(.*?)<h1>(.*?)<\\/h1>/s"; 
$str = "a\n    - hello -\n    <h1> hello </h1>\n    - hello -\n    <h1> hello </h1>"; 
$subst = "$1$2<h2>$3<h2>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output:

```
a
    - hello -
    <h2> hello <h2>
    - hello -
    <h2> hello <h2>
```

*EDIT*: My approach yields access to the submatches while Avinash Raj's only dwells on actual deilimiter replacement.

Comment: What do you mean by `My approach yields access to the submatches while Avinash Raj's only dwells on actual deilimiter replacement.` ?

Comment: Consider a situation when b b is actually <b> he b llo </b>

Comment: When I change regex to (a|(?<!^)\G)(.*?)\bb\b(.*?)\b<\/b>\b it stops work :(

Comment: @holden321 edit your question with exact input and expected output, since i didn't find any `<b> he b llo </b>` tags on your input.

Comment: It is just a structure :) In real life it can be any text :)

Comment: Your regex replaces any tag now))

Comment: I want to replace exact tags) Like <h2> </h2> to <h1> <h1> for example)

Comment: @holden321 it wold be better if you made an edit on your question.

Comment: Great, I am very happy it works for you! :) Time for lunch :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with `z`

```
(?:a|(?<!^)\G).*?\Kb
```

And don't forget to enable DOTALL modifier `s`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM0hA6/2)

**Example:**

```
$string = <<<EOT
a
    - hello -
    b hello b
    - hello -
    b hello b
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~(?:a|(?<!^)\G).*?\Kb~s', 'z', $string);
```

**Output:**

```
a
    - hello -
    z hello z
    - hello -
    z hello z
```

Comment: Well, your answer is really, rally cool. You are master. But b is actually a html tag, this is like <b>hello</b>. But this is my fault :(

Comment: Yes but what if "b" inside b1-b2: "b1 hel b lo b2"?